# Query without precision brings different result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql

I have pasted a formula from Excel and pasted onto SQL Server Management Studio.

Once I execute it, I get an unexpected result:

```
SELECT (((10320238-2092189)/2092189)*100.0)/4.0 --returns 75.000000
```

But after adding precision to each value within query, it returns the correct result:

```
SELECT (((10320238.0-2092189.0)/2092189.0)*100.0)/4.0 --returns 98.31866289250000
```

Why the first query won't bring 98% as result? 
What is the inner data type of `10320238`? Is it `integer`?

The engine is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3) (KB3072779) - 11.0.6020.0 (X64) 
    Oct 20 2015 15:36:27 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Just try `SELECT 7 / 2 ;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called "integer math" - when you divide two integers, any remainder is discarded. Compare:

```
SELECT integers = (10320238-2092189)/2092189, 
       decimals = (10320238.0-2092189.0)/2092189.0;
```

Results:

```
integers    decimals
--------    ------------
3           3.9327465157
```

From the [division topic in Books Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/divide-transact-sql):

> If an integer dividend is divided by an integer divisor, the result is an integer that has any fractional part of the result truncated.